# Change input -> change checkbox model without click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

If you update text input model "sg.Value", checkbox shoud be checked, but model "sg.AnswerId" is not set.

[image: Sample]

How to get:

Change text input -> Set checkbox model ?

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox"
         ng-model="sg.AnswerId"
         ng-true-value="'{{answer.Id}}'"
         ng-checked="sg.Value != undefined"
         >
  <input type="text"
         placeholder="Your text"
         ng-model="sg.Value"
         >
</label>
```

Checkbox must become checked and it's model updated, when i typing in input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aeycTFW9Mvp9EQTNl1QM?p=preview)

Listener on input change:

```
function trackInput(){
  if(sg.Value !== '' && sg.Value !== undefined) {
    sg.AnswerId = sg.answer.Id;
  } else {
    sg.AnswerId = false;
  }
};
```

Maybe anyone have better solution? Share please.